# How to publish Generic Access service on Raspberry Pi as peripheral?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am in the process to mimic a real-world BLE device on a Pi Zero.

I installed all needed packages and updated Bluez to version 5.50. Starting off from the python advertising sample and service sample I built a combined sample that advertises and implements a Battery service and a custom service.

Advertising, pairing, connecting and accessing the services works so far, but the advertised interface is missing the Generic Access service (UUID 1800) so it doesn't provide a Device Name Characteristic (UUID 2a00) nor an Apperance Characteristic (UUID 2a01).

I was able to add a Device Information service (UUID 180a) for both service registration and advertising. I get an error when I try to register a Generic Access service:

```
Failed to register application: org.bluez.Error.Failed: Failed to create entry in database
```

As Generic Access and Device Information are mandatory, the resulting advertisement dosn't comply to the standard.

**Is there a way to add the Generic Access service to an application?**

When browsingconsuming the interface from an Android phone using BLE Scanner, the advertised services are only accessible when implemented properly in the application.
In contrast to the Bluez implementation, the reference real-world device provids the Generic Access service.
As a result, the Bluez implemntation peripheral isn't recognized by the application that should consume the services.

TIA,
Helge

Comment: Do you use bleno?

Comment: Mike: he says he uses BlueZ, so obviously no. Helge: your terminology is a bit confusing when you say "advertised interface". Do you mean that you include the service uuid in your advertisement data or just that it is present in the GATT db? I also don't think you can add a custom GAP service in BlueZ since, just as on iOS and Android, it's a system defined service and not a custom one. If you use a custom HCI-talking software that bypasses BlueZ, you can configure your services however you want.

Comment: I include the UUID (1800) in the advertising data. Can't add it to the GATT DB since that causes an error message. To my experience with other BLE implementations, it should be in the GATT DB too.

Comment: I added a custom service (long UUID) successfully. It's the standard service that causes problems.